# Custom Camelization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there any way to specify exceptions for `camelize`?

For example, if I wanted `camelize('uses_sql')` to be `usesSQL` instead of the what `camelize` produces by default, `usesSql`. This doesn't seem to be covered by the standard [inflections exception config](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/42-how-to-automatically-pluralize-text-in-ruby-on-rails).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be supported in Rails 3.2 with [acronym](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym).

For Rail 3.1, I created a custom version by copying some of the relevant methods in [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/initializers) to override default behavior.